# How to filter Supabase Postgres CDC subscription using multiple conditions

Tags: postgresql, supabase

How can I filter a Supabase Postgres CDC query using multiple conditions?

```
channel.on('postgres_changes', { event: 'UPDATE', schema: 'public', table: 'users', 
  filter: 'username=eq.Realtime' }, (payload) => {
  console.log('All updates on users table when username is Realtime: ', payload)
})
```

Instead of: `filter: 'username=eq.Realtime'`

I'd like to do: `filter: 'username=eq.Realtime&&firstname=neq.test'`

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Currently, Supabase realtime engine only allows for 1 filter to be applied. In your case, you would just have to ignore all the data that does not meet the condition you would like with good old `if` statements.

```js
channel.on('postgres_changes',
  {
    event: 'UPDATE',
    schema: 'public',
    table: 'users', 
    filter: 'username=eq.Realtime'
  }, (payload) => {
    // Check if the data meets the additional condition you would like.
    if(payload.new.firstname == 'test') {
      console.log('All updates on users table when username is Realtime: ', payload)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm doing at the moment. The app is reordering and editing large sets of data, so I was hoping to reduce the amount of data being returned from Supabase

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to have another table ('smaller') with the bare minimum rows duplicated from the 'main' table. Listen to the 'smaller', filter out the unwanted rows, and fetch the required data from the 'main'.

You could consider caching the data, and only fetch new/modified rows.